# Comparing equality of two complex objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have two List, this complex object has 4 public properties of reference type.
How can i compare one list to another to find if those lists are equal in size and by values.

I have implemented Equals in ComplexObject in order to help with equality checks

```
public Type1 Type1 { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Type2> Type2s{ get; set; }
public Type3 Type3{ get; set; }
public Type4 Type4 { get; set; }

public bool Equals(ComplexObject complexObject)
{
    int type2sCount = Type2s.Count();
    return Type1 .Equals(complexObject.Type1) &&
        Type3.Equals(complexObject.Type3) &&
        Type4.Equals(complexObject.Type4) &&
        Type2s.Intersect(complexObject.Type2s).Count() == type2sCount;
}
```

I need also to print out items that do no fit or have no pair in second list

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach for the lists would be `SequenceEqual`, but you need to be careful about `null`s:

```
public bool Equals(ComplexObject complexObject)
{
    bool eq = Equals(Type1, complexObject.Type1)
        && Equals(Type3, complexObject.Type3)
        && Equals(Type4, complexObject.Type4);
    if (eq)
    {
        if(Type2s == null)
        {
            if(complexObject.Type2s != null) eq = false;
        } else {
            eq = complexObject.Type2s == null ? false
               : Type2s.SequenceEqual(complexObject.Type2s);
        }
    }
    return eq;
}
```

Comment: Should i sort list prior using this approach ?

Comment: @eugeneK that depends... do you consider them as "sets" or "sequences"? I would propose that the sequence `{1,2,3}` **is not** equal to the sequence `{1,3,2}`, however if we consider them as *sets*: they are. Either way, I wouldn't do any sorting. If we were treating them as *sets*, I would probably use a `HashSet<T>` buffer or something. Of course, then it gets tricky if you consider `{1,1,2,3}` to be different to `{1,2,3}`, because if we are treating them as sets: they are the same.

Comment: Well these are sets, so i can use your Equals suggestion along with @Charlie - BlokeTech answer. Unless there is a better solution. I couldn't get how HasSet<T> would help me though.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort both lists first, you can use the **SequencyEqual** extension method to check that both sequences are equal. This method is part of System.Linq.

Here's an example:

```
    List<ComplexObject> list1 = new List<ComplexObject>();
    List<ComplexObject> list2 = new List<ComplexObject>();

    IOrderedEnumerable<ComplexObject> list1Sorted = list1.OrderBy(item => item.SomeProperty);
    IOrderedEnumerable<ComplexObject> list2Sorted = list2.OrderBy(item => item.SomeProperty);

    bool areEqual = list1Sorted.SequenceEqual(list2Sorted);
```

Comment: This also depends on whether you consider the sequences `{1,2,3}` and `{1,3,2}` to be "equal"... sometimes you do, sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the IEqualityComparer(T).
You implement the interface members and if you are using LINQ, it will work, you should be able to AND the lists.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx

Comment: Is there any generic Comparer so i can use it for other kind of objects ?

Comment: @eugeneK yes: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of **SequenceEqual(List1, List2)**

```
  bool equal = Type2s.SequenceEqual(complexObject.Type2s);
```